# Transient Error: "too many connections for role" in ASP.NET Core project with PostgreSQL and Entity Framework Core

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, dbcontext, .net-7.0, transient

In my `ASP.NET Core` project, which uses `PostgreSQL` as the database and Entity Framework Core for data access, I'm running into a recurring problem. I'm getting the following error message on and off:

```
{"Message":"An error occurred while processing your request.","ExceptionMessage":"53300: too many connections for role \"yxyjmsin\"","ExceptionType":"Npgsql.PostgresException"}
{"Message":"An error occurred while processing your request.","ExceptionMessage":"An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

This error seems to be related to an excessive number of open database connections. I have tried various configurations and code changes, but I'm still struggling to pinpoint the root cause and resolve the issue.

This is how I added dbcontext in my `Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
{
    var configuration = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
    var builder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(configuration.GetConnectionString("ElephantSQL"));
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.ConnectionString, npgsqlOptions => 
    {
        npgsqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
        npgsqlOptions.MaxBatchSize(5);
    });
    builder.MapEnum<UserRole>();
    builder.MapEnum<OrderStatus>();
    options.AddInterceptors(new TimeStampInterceptor());
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Build()).UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
});
```

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ElephantSQL": "Server=myServer;Port=5432;Username=yxyjmsin;Password=myPasswd;Database=myDb Pooling=true;"
 },
```

usage of applicationdbcontext in my base repo

```
public async Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            try
            {
                if (entity is User userEntity)
                {
                    if (userEntity.Role != UserRole.Admin)
                    {
                        userEntity.Role = UserRole.Customer;
                    }
                }
                var entry = await _dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
                await _applicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                return entry.Entity;
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException ex)
            {                
                Console.WriteLine("Base Repository exception.");
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I had the configuration of my db in the `ApplicationDbContext` file but moved to `Program.cs` with hopes that it was going to resolve the transient issue but it didnt.

I checked the `rolconnlimit` which was 5 and so did set `maxbatchsize` to 5.

I've enabled retry on failure in the database connection configuration and noticed this error in the console:
Exception data:

```
Severity: FATAL
SqlState: 53300
MessageText: too many connections for role "yxyjmsin"
File: miscinit.c
  
Line: 734
Routine: InitializeSessionUserId
```

Could you please help me fix this issue in my code?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: can you put down some of your codes when you are using `ApplicationDbContext`?

Comment: You also should be inclined to check your [Pg_stat_activity](https://www.commandprompt.com/education/how-to-list-sessionsactive-connections-in-postgresql/#:~:text=Postgres%20allows%20you%20to%20find,client%20host%20for%20each%20session.) when this error occurs to see how many connections your app is making to the db,it could be an external app as well making these connections.

Comment: @MajidParvin I have updated my question with applicationdbcontext usage in my base repo

Comment: Where do you dispose ‘ApplicationDbContext‘ in the repo? Make sure the dbContext is being disposed each time

Comment: how do i do that? I read some resource, I actually tot thats been handle automatically by c#. If its not so, could you let please show me how to do that?

This is a  
[link](https://github.com/SamAddy/.Net-Fullstack-Ecommerce/blob/main/EcommerceBackend/EcommerceBackend.Framework/src/Repositories/BaseRepository.cs)
to how my whole base repo if it helps.

Comment: I read thru this [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/) and noticed I seem to have quite similar way of handling dbcontext. But not sure if i need to use this style


var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Test")
    .Options;

using var context = new ApplicationDbContext(contextOptions);

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things that could be wrong with your code:

1. Your connection string doesn't seem to be okay. you missed `;` before `Pooling=true`
2. change the connection string to have more options regarding the pooling like: `Server=myServer;Port=5432;Username=yxyjmsin;Password=myPasswd;Database=myDb;Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;`

if those didn't work, try the connection string without pooling: `Server=myServer;Port=5432;Username=yxyjmsin;Password=myPasswd;Database=myDb;` and also without batch config:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
{
    var configuration = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
    var builder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(configuration.GetConnectionString("ElephantSQL"));
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.ConnectionString, npgsqlOptions => npgsqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(3));
    builder.MapEnum<UserRole>();
    builder.MapEnum<OrderStatus>();
    options.AddInterceptors(new TimeStampInterceptor());
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Build()).UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
});
```

Comment: I did add minimum and maximum pool to my connection string so it worked for sometime but later threw a new error which is still about too many connections for role yxyjmsin. 

I tried the second option as well and it didnt work. So i decided to use special instance in each method but that ended up with same error.
using var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(_dbContextOptions);

Comment: Im not sure if the issue might be related to how the services are added in [program.cs file](https://github.com/SamAddy/.Net-Fullstack-Ecommerce/blob/main/EcommerceBackend/EcommerceBackend.Framework/src/Program.cs)
error:
The maximum number of retries (3) was exceeded while executing database operations with \u0027NpgsqlRetryingExecutionStrategy\u0027